# Одновременная обработка двух таймеров с анимацией

Tags: c++

пишу на WinForms(c++) простой файтинг, за передвижение игроков отвечают таймеры(активируются при нажатии клавиш) , которые обновляют расположение PictureBox’oв(игроков), после, решил добавить анимацию бега(switch с 24 изображениями) в таймерах, когда два игрока одновременно начинают бежать , происходит замедление анимации и бега, поодиночке все хорошо, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.

```cpp
int run_right_animation = 0;
int run_left_animation = 0;
int run_right_animation_second_player = 0;
int run_left_animation_second_player = 0;
```

```
//определяет какая клавиша нажата, и затем запускает нужный таймер.
private: System::Void Form1_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e)
{       

    switch (e->KeyValue)
    {
    case 65:    
        timer1->Enabled = true;
        break;
    case 68:        
        timer2->Enabled = true;
        break;
    case 37:
        timer3->Enabled = true;
        break;
    case 39:
        timer4->Enabled = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

```cpp
//при отпускании останавливает таймер с передвижением.
private: System::Void Form1_KeyUp(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e)
    {           
            switch (e->KeyValue)
        {
        case 65:    
            timer1->Enabled = false;
            break;
        case 68:        
            timer2->Enabled = false;
            break;
        case 37:
            timer3->Enabled = false;
            break;
        case 39:
            timer4->Enabled = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

```cpp
//два таймера для движения и анимации левого pictureBox`a, и два для правого.
private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(pictureBox1->Location.X - 20, pictureBox1->Location.Y);

    run_left_animation++;

    switch (run_left_animation)
    {
    case 1:
        pictureBox1->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::DesktopDirectory) + "\\runspriteleft1.png");
        break;

    //
    //еще 22 повторения
    //

    case 24:
        pictureBox1->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::DesktopDirectory) + "\\runspriteleft8.png");
        run_left_animation = 0;
        break;
    }
}

private: System::Void timer2_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(pictureBox1->Location.X - 20, pictureBox1->Location.Y);

    run_right_animation++;

    switch (run_right_animation)
    {
    case 1:
        pictureBox1->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::DesktopDirectory) + "\\runspriteleft1.png");
        break;

    //
    //еще 22 повторения
    //

    case 24:
        pictureBox1->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::DesktopDirectory) + "\\runspriteleft8.png");
        run_right_animation = 0;
        break;
    }
}

private: System::Void timer3_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    pictureBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(pictureBox2->Location.X - 20, pictureBox2->Location.Y);

    run_right_animation_second_player++;

    switch (run_right_animation_second_player)
    {
    case 1:
        pictureBox2->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::DesktopDirectory) + "\\runspriteleft1.png");
        break;

    //
    //еще 22 повторения
    //

    case 24:
        pictureBox2->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::DesktopDirectory) + "\\runspriteleft8.png");
        run_right_animation_second_player = 0;
        break;
    }
}

private: System::Void timer4_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    pictureBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(pictureBox2->Location.X - 20, pictureBox2->Location.Y);

    run_left_animation_second_player++;

    switch (run_left_animation_second_player)
    {
    case 1:
        pictureBox2->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::DesktopDirectory) + "\\runspriteleft1.png");
        break;

    //
    //еще 22 повторения
    //

    case 24:
        pictureBox2->Image = System::Drawing::Image::FromFile(Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::DesktopDirectory) + "\\runspriteleft8.png");
        run_left_animation_second_player = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Существует 1000500 способов наделать ошибок в реализации того, что Вы написали. Нужен Ваш код. Гляньте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Изменил. Есть догадки в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Я видел, минус убрал.  Если будет время попробую разобраться в Вашей проблеме. Вам нужно привлечь внимание к своему вопросу. Для этого существуют два способа - первый, попросить кого-нить из гуру с "бесконечным рейтингом" объявить конкурс (у Вас пока недостаточно  рейтинга, чтобы самому выставить свой вопрос на конкурс), но это можно будет сделать только, через два дня. Второй (небольшой мухлеж) внести в свой вопрос некоторое изменение, чтобы он вновь отобразился в списке текущих вопросов. Однако, это лучше делать в понедельник, когда на форуме много народа :)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Понял, спасибо.